# How to add multiple SHA1 fingerprints to my Android App for testing?

Tags: android, google-signin, android-app-signing

My Android App already has a SHA1 fingerprint on Google developers console generated by another developer some time back. Now, I am debugging Google Sign-in bug in the App and it turns out that Google Sign in uses the default SHA-1 found in `.android/debug.keystore` to make a request in the OAuth authentication process. And I had generated a new debug key yesterday because after all it is debug.

How do I add or incorporate this new debug key to Google's developer console to make a successful Sign in request?(I don't want to replace the old key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Google Cloud Platform Console or Firebase. You'll find the project there. Click on the project and you'll get into the dashboard of the same. In the bottom of the dashboard there'll be SHA key. Click add key and add the new key there. The Google Services which you have used in the app will run fine now.

Comment: I tried this but Firebase displays an error message saying that it only allows 1 unique fingerprint per project so it can't do it.

Comment: Finally found the problem. Had another duplicate project with the same key I was trying to add(I had added it earlier but had slipped out of my mind). Anyway thanks.