# How do I use google sign In in my android app without certificating SHA-1 fingerprint in my firastore database?

Tags: android, sign, google-signin

So, I just integrated Google Sign In on my app perfectly, the app receives the user instance and its data. But I wanna know if it is possible to run my app in a release mode or something like that, in order to avoid adding a SHA-1 fingerprint everytime one person wants to sign in via Google Account?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what the SHA-1 fingerprint is for. Your app has a SHA-1 fingerprint which basically identifies the app. You can set it in your Firebase settings. Once you have set this SHA-1 fingerprint, you will not need to set it again.

Comment: @A.S.H sorry I think I've not explain myself correctly, I'm working in my app with another person, and he can't sign in via google in the app if I don't add his SHA-1, because when he executes signinReports in the gradle console, he gets a different SHA-1 from mine, besides it's the same project

Comment: Can't you just add his SHA-1 too? This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396575/how-to-add-multiple-sha1-fingerprints-to-my-android-app-for-testing